# Devirtualization in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Does visual c++ devirtualize a function for a pure class that only has one implementation?
For example:

```
class ICar
{
public:
virtual void Break() = 0;
};

class CarImpl : public ICar
{
public:
virtual void Break(){ .... }
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term devirtualization, are you asking if there's a runtime lookup cost?

Comment: Devirtualization is undoing the virtual command.  It makes a function available for use.  But the wording here is a bit tricky... Do you mean "does it automatically devirtualize it when used?"

Comment: If it does it, I will only do it where it can _prove_ the type that the function is being called on.

Comment: It is never safe to do this optimisation unless it happens at link time -- since what if another translation unit contained a second class derived from `ICar`?  The only optimisation I'm aware of is that if the dynamic type of an object is known at compile time, the compiler will use a non-virtual call (or inline it). E.g.: `ICar *x = new CarImpl; x->Break();` will use a direct call almost for sure.

Comment: Make sure your car will also get a Brake() function, so it won't Break() all the time.

Comment: I *think* he's asking if it generates a vtable for an abstract class that is only inherited by one other class, instead of using a static method table. ?

Comment: I asking if interface to has only one implementation does compiler change all these virtual calls to non-virtual calls ?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: in your case, virtual table is involved. But if you have `CarImpl x; x.Break();` then the optimizing compiler will resolve the call at compilation time.

Comment: @Alex: The case you describe will certainly be resolved at compile time by any decent compiler.  My case ought to be resolved by a compiler with a good optimiser. Did you look at the generated assembly?

Comment: @j-random-hacker: yes I did, both in VS 2010 and g++ 4.6. But you're right, this **could be** optimized.

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, I've just tested it myself with MSVC++ 2009. I'm amazed that it doesn't work, even with `CarImpl x; ICar& r(x); r.Break();` and /O2 optimisation. It would speed up any code that uses a factory function in the same translation unit to build instances of classes derived from some base class.

Answer (score 7):

The OP question naturally breaks up into 3 questions:

1. Does VC++ 2010 do the described devirtualization - the answer is:
   **No**
2. Could it have done it - the answer is: **Yes** theoretically it could have been
   done in some situations.
3. Why doesn't VC++ do it. - we can only speculate...

Here are the details:

### 1. Is such optimization done by VC++

To prove that this optimization is not done we need to enable assembler language listing in Project Properties/ Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Output Files: set Assembler Output to "Assembly With Source Code" (/FAs)".

Here is the slightly modified C++ code from the OP (I changed ICar from abstract class to normal, it does not change the gist of the question):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class ICar
{
public:
    virtual void Accelerate(){printf("%s", "a\n");};
    virtual void Break(){printf("%s", "b\n");};
};

class CarImpl : public ICar
{
public:
    virtual void Accelerate(){ printf("%s", "accelerate\n"); }
    virtual void Break(){ printf("%s", "break\n"); }
    void Fly() { printf("%s", "fly\n"); }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ICar *pCar = new CarImpl();
    pCar->Break();

    CarImpl *pCarImpl = new CarImpl();
    pCarImpl->Fly();

    CarImpl carImpl;
    carImpl.Break();
    carImpl.Fly();

    return 0;
}
```

First, (**NOTE 1**) let's notice that `carImpl.Break();` does NOT use virtual function. This is not a consequence of optimization - it is a feature of C++: If the type of object is known during compilation, the mechanism of virtual functions is not employed. The mechanism of virtual functions is only used when pointers or references are involved.

Second, let's enable optimization /O2 and see the assembler generated for `pCar->Break();` (virtual method) and `pCarImpl->Fly();` (non-virtual method).

For call to Break() we will see:

```
; 24   :     pCar->Break();

    mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
    mov ecx, eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+4]
    call    eax
```

EAX contains a pointer to CarImpl object (it is clear from the preceding lines of assembler not shown here). In the first mov instruction the first dword of CarImpl object is loaded into EDX (the first dword of an object is usually the address of vtbl), then `this` of CarImpl is loaded in ECX (this is not important for us), then the dword with the offset 4 from the point where EDX points (the second function in the table of virtual functions) is loaded into EAX, and then the call is done.

In case of Fly() we will see:

```
; 27   :     pCarImpl->Fly();

    push    OFFSET ??_C@_04PPJAHJOB@fly?6?$AA@
    push    OFFSET ??_C@_02DKCKIIND@?$CFs?$AA@
    call    _printf
```

This is just inlining of printf with two parameters passed to it.

So, obviously the use of vtable is not optimized out in case of Break().

### 2. Could such optimization be done

In principal it could be optimized. I found the following statement in "The Annotated C++ Reference Manual" by M.Ellis, B. Stroustrup, Addison-Wesley 1990: chapter 10.2 (I have this book in translation, and I'm translating back to English :-) so it may be not the exact wording of Stroustroup.)

*When the exact type of object is known at compilation time the mechanism of virtual functions is not necessary. Instead, the realization can generate an ordinary call of the class member function. (DK: the case of carImpl.Break() in our code, see my NOTE 1)
...
When a virtual function is called via pointer or reference, the actual type of object may not be statically known, hence the mechanism of virtual functions should be used. A compiler with enough knowledge of the control flow can drop calls to virtual functions even in some cases like calls via bp in the following code:*

```
struct base {
    virtual void vf1();
}
class derived : public base{
public:
    void vf1();
}

void g()
{
    derived d;
    base* bp = &d;
    bp->vf1();
}
```

*...
The inline virtual functions make full sense and are used quite often. Naturally, inlining is used only in places where an inline function is applied to an object of known type. (DK: I think here B. Stroustrup also refers to our case of carImpl.Break(); i.e. the case described in NOTE1).*

### 3. Why it is not done

Although this was not literally asked in the OP, maybe it was a hidden question. I agree with one of comments by Alex Cohn (well said):

*It could, but it doesn't. Probably this does not happen often enough to justify the resources required to optimize such calls reliably.*

Comment: Mostly good, except for your `Test(carImpl);` which has nothing to do with virtual functions -- what that function call actually demonstrates is a phenomenon called *object slicing*, which is really an insidious design problem in C++ itself: passing a derived class to a function taking a base class *by value* causes all derived members to be sliced off, and the object is treated as a base class instance.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Thanks for this term _object slicing_! It was exactly my point that calling methods on objects of statically known type like on Test's parameter `ICar car`, or another example would be a cast like this `CarImpl ci; ((ICar)ci).Break();` has nothing to do with virtual functions. Function declared in this statically known class will always be used - not a polymorphic substitution through vtable. Just put it to be clear on that. :-) Interesting to note that in C# a similar code (with passing parameter or cast) will call the polymorphic method.

Comment: I still think you're muddying the waters by using an example that causes object slicing (a serious and subtle problem) to make a point about virtual function calls. `carImpl.Break();` is already a good (non-confusing) example of what you're talking about.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: You have a point. I've removed the Test() function.

Comment: I tested the testcase with GCC and it gets optimized into a sequence of puts with two calls to new.  So it seems the optimization is indeed valid.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This answer is obsoleted by my second answer of 2012-10-20. I did not delete it to preserve the comments.

It is not possible for VC++ because other derived classes can be linked to the already compiled dll or exe module.

Comment: That's true, but VC++ does have `/LTCG` for link-time code generation, meaning that it potentially could implement the optimisation there.

Comment: It could, but it doesn't. Probably this does not happen often enough to justify the resources required to optimize such calls reliably.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: To use /LTCG in the link time the modules must be compiled with /GL in first place. If you have a compiled module from somebody else it is not likely that they compiled with /GL.

Comment: I got curious myself and enabled Profile Guided Optimization (/LTCG:PGOptimize) which caused my small program to be reoptimized after linking. I enabled all possible optimization for speed and I also enabled Assembler listing (/FAs). I the produced assembler I see that call to break is still done via Virtual Table `; 22   :     p->Break();

 mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax]
 mov ecx, eax
 mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
 call eax
` while another non-virtual function which I added to the CarImpl actually got inlined in place of its call.

Comment: @Denis: Thanks for testing it. What was the code you tested exactly? I want to know whether the compiler could have proved that it knew the dynamic type of the object at compile time (e.g. `ICar *p = new CarImpl; p->Break();` or not (if a function declared as returning `ICar*` was called in a different translation unit than where it was defined, and this function actually returns a point to a `CarImpl` object).